# how to create a column with their groups present as separate column created by spread() in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this screenshot which I achieved using spread() in R. In the screenshot below, if there is completed or scheduled date present then max of those 2 are selected else max of cancelled date is selected and given it to "max_appointment_date" column. Now I need a column which says which group date does max_appointment_date belongs to? Any suggestions will be helpful!, thank you!
[image]

To achieve:

cancelled | Completed | Scheduled |  max_appointment_date | max_appointment_status

2022-10-17 | 2022-10-10| 2022-09-05 |  2022-10-10 |             Completed

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt from the example below for a dplyr solution. Please note your description doesn't indicate what to enter if both Completed and Scheduled dates are the same.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create data set
data <- tibble(Cancelled = c("2022-10-17",
                     "2022-10-14",
                     "2022-02-23",
                     "2022-10-05",
                     "2022-10-10"),
       Completed = c("2022-10-10",
                     "2022-09-13",
                     "2022-04-13",
                     "2022-05-25",
                     "2022-06-24"),
       Scheduled = c("2022-09-05",
                     "2022-10-11",
                     "2022-10-12",
                     "2022-10-12",
                     "2022-10-12")
       ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~lubridate::ymd(.)))

# Add columns for 'max_appointment_date' and ' max_appointment_status'

data %>%
  mutate(
    max_appointment_date = case_when(
      Completed > Scheduled ~ Completed,
      TRUE ~ Scheduled
    ),
    max_appointment_status = case_when(
      Completed > Scheduled ~ "Completed",
      TRUE ~ "Scheduled"
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Seth for the answer! I appreciate it.
The code below also worked for me:

```
data %>%
mutate(max_appointment_date = case_when((!is.na(Completed) | !is.na(Scheduled) ) ~ pmax(Completed, Scheduled, na.rm = TRUE),
                                        is.na(Completed) & is.na(Scheduled) & !is.na(Cancelled) ~ Cancelled),
      max_statusgroup = case_when(max_appointment_date == Completed ~ 'Completed',
                                  max_appointment_date == Scheduled ~ 'Scheduled',
                                  max_appointment_date == Cancelled ~ 'Cancelled')))
```